# I have six images with names and i want them in the footer side by side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have six images with names and I want to place them in the footer.
After placing the names are displaying in two lines instead of a single line. that is "s player" where "s" is displaying above the "player" instead of in a single line in smaller devices so how to make responsive to resolve this issue?.`

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 45pt;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2pt 8pt;
    border-top: 1pt solid #f3f3f4;
}

span {
  font-family: Segoe Script;
}

.super {
  color: #9400D3;
  text-size-adjust: inherit;
}

.duper {
  color: #4B0082;
}

.champ {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.good {
  color: #FF7F00;
}

.hero {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.king {
  color: #00BD13;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col s2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <img src="/images/abc.svg" alt="Player1">
            <div><span class="super">s</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <img src="/images/bcd.svg" alt="Player2">
            <div><span class="duper">d</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <img src="/images/cde.svg" alt="Player3">
            <div><span class="champ">c</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <img src="/images/def.svg" alt="Player4">
            <div><span class="good">g</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <img src="/images/efg.svg" alt="Player5">
            <div><span class="hero">h</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <img src="/images/fgh.svg" alt="Player6">
            <div><span class="king">k</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem come here from all the class `col-xx` that you use in you children in `row`. They have to have all the same width so please just use a single `col` class :

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 45pt;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2pt 8pt;
    border-top: 1pt solid #f3f3f4;
}

span {
  font-family: Segoe Script;
}

.super {
  color: #9400D3;
  text-size-adjust: inherit;
}

.duper {
  color: #4B0082;
}

.champ {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.good {
  color: #FF7F00;
}

.hero {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/abc.svg" alt="Player1">
            <div><span class="super">s</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/bcd.svg" alt="Player2">
            <div><span class="duper">d</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/cde.svg" alt="Player3">
            <div><span class="champ">c</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/def.svg" alt="Player4">
            <div><span class="good">g</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/efg.svg" alt="Player5">
            <div><span class="hero">h</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="/images/fgh.svg" alt="Player6">
            <div><span class="king">k</span> Player</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I tried this as well but in smaller devices like Galaxy S5 and Nexus 6 it is not showing all the six images but It displays only 4 images and 5 images respectively.

Comment: I am using this code to create app so can you tell me how can I change the code to display all six images with their names?

Comment: @GirishKallihal Remove the `bottom: 0px` of your `.footer` and you will see that the others images are actually below. it comes from the fact that the 6 images put end to end are too wide to be contained in a single row. The only option is to reduce their size

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time in answering this.

Comment: @GirishKallihal Ahah not a problem ;)

Comment: I have tried the above code but the problem is the images are not aligned centre they are shifted to right side little bit. So I want images at the centre and the text below them is also centre with respect to the images.

Comment: @GirishKallihal Please open for that a new question ;) Then I'll be happy to help you.